# UPDATE on SELECT results. A SQL query to swap Author with Meta Box value

Tags: custom-field, users, mysql, sql

I inherited a project where, for some reason, the previous developer make a custom post type for authors and a custom select listing all those authors cpt titles in the post edit screen. This led to a lot of additional code to handle permalinks, templates, edits, and custom queries while all of this could be achieved out of the box.

So, I've already found a way to create all the missing users out of the author cpts. Now I am looking for an SQL command or script to swap the regular author with the new one based on the mata_key value. For some posts however, this value could be `null`.

With this SQL query I group all the posts with a certain fake_author id:

`SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts JOIN wp_postmeta a ON ( a.post_id = wp_posts.ID AND a.meta_key='fake_author' AND a.meta_value = '111111');`

How can I perform an update in the post_author column for the resulting posts?

My attempt so far:

`UPDATE wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta a ON ( a.post_id = wp_posts.ID AND a.meta_key='fake_author' AND a.meta_value=111111)
SET post_author=2222222;`

However, this gives no results.

Comment: just write a proper php code which uses the WP API for that

Answer (score 0):

I always find it way less confusing to get the results from one table and loop them rather than to try to join them like that... eg.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='fake_author' AND meta_value='11111'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $query = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author='222222' WHERE ID='".$result->post_id."'";
    $wpdb->query($query);
}
```

Comment: Hi @majick thank you for your answer. I've found a similar snippet, however, it brings me back to using PHP code which is what I was looking to avoid. There are also a couple of SQL solutions using a temp table which is very close to yours. At the end, as I needed to get the job done quickly, I created a complete function in PHP with a slightly different logic, nevertheless, the question remains as I would really like to understand what's the proper SQL syntax to perform the UPDATE